# Android Studio- Why is this image button closing my app?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, jsoup

Theres a image button that should bring my to a different activity but it closes my app. Any one have any ideas as to why?

```
ImageButton imagebtn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebtn2);
        imagebtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                Intent intent = new Intent
                        (Scrape.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

This is my code, the MainActivity is the same code just different names. Below is my manifest.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Scrape"
            android:label="@string/app_name1"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </activity>
```

This is my xml.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imagebtn1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/got" />
```

And the second image buttons xml

Comment: You have invalid manifest .. action and category are supposed to be in <intent-filter> for .Scrape activity

Comment: i had them in , still didnt work, the debugger said it was this line...imagebtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: Just remove **whole** `<intent-filter>` from `.MainActivity` (it doesn't need it since it's not the launcher activity, `.Scrape` is, as far as I can see from your code.

Comment: no mainactivity is the launcher class i want

Answer (score 0):

If its on line with `setOnClickListener` then its NullPointerException because the IDs are different and you will get null in imageBtn2.
If you have debugger, the exception would help a **lot** .. thats why the exceptions are there!